# What Firewall settings needs to be enabled for Airdrop?

Tags: system-settings, firewall, airdrop

Which option in the built-in firewall in System Preferences needs to be enabled to allow AirDrop to receive files on a Mac?

The Mac can currently see iPhone's and other devices in Airdrop, but does not show on the iPhone as a target for Airdrop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall
2. Select Firewall Options
3. In the list set "sharingd" to "Allow Incoming Connections"

Alternatively, tick "Automatically allow built-in software to receive incoming connections"

[image: System Preferences Firewall Settings for Airdrop]

Comment: Thank you. It does work for me. Would you set it as accepted answer, it will be easier to search and find.

Comment: If `sharingd` is not listed, add `/usr/libexec/sharingd` via:
click **+** , then press `/` to allow typing a path, then enter `/usr/libexec/` then select `sharingd`